# Datastax-agent is not starting

Tags: cassandra, jmx, datastax-enterprise

I had 5 node Cassandra/spark cluster configured using Ops-center,from which I removed one node as it was needing it for different purpose. Now I am trying to add the same node to cluster.

Datastax-agent is getting installed successfully but on starting datastax-agent it is giving below error :

> **Error connecting via JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]**

**address.yaml:**

```
stomp_interface: 10.20.210.40

hosts: ["10.20.210.40"]

use_ssl: 0
```

Also, Before removing node I was using java 7,after removing I switched to java 8 and now before adding the node I  switched back to java 7. Does it cause any problem?

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/JmxGotchas

Comment: Is C* up and running?

Comment: No. I  removed it from Casandra cluster as well.